# TCL list avoid spliting of string

Tags: list, split, tcl

Is there a way to avoid splitting of strings in a list ?

For example, I have a list where I append several strings with spaces :

```
set l [list]
lappend l "hello guy how are you ?"
lappend l "chocolate is very good"
```

and then I want to handle each string in the list via a foreach loop :

```
foreach str $l {
   puts "$str"
}
```

but when it arrives to the last string in the list, all the elements of this last string are split. How to avoid this ?

Thanks.

Comment: When I execute your example, the strings are not split.

Comment: me too. What does `puts $l` show you? I would expect to see `{hello guy how are you ?} {chocolate is very good}`

Comment: sorry I did a mistake of splitting before adding in the list. The list works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that what you have is actually somewhere that does:

```
lappend l "chocolate" "is" "very" "good"
# And not this...
#lappend l "chocolate is very good"
```

That's a very important distinction. The `lappend` command is *variadic*; it takes as many arguments as you supply (after the variable name) and appends each of them as its own list element to the given variable. This means that omitting the quoting will not result in an error; it's correct and useful *in general* even if not in your particular case.

Note that `lappend` is careful; it won't mis-quote anything.

---

The other possibility is that you used `append` instead of `lappend`. That appends its arguments as a *string* instead of as list items. (It just happens that many sentences look a lot like Tcl lists.) The difference between the two commands is fundamental, and perhaps a little easy to miss if you are in a hurry.

```
append l " chocolate is very good"
# vs.
lappend l " chocolate is very good"
```

Comment: Thank you for this comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Appending is a best way to avoid such situations. Simplified Append:

```
 % set l [list]
 % set l "$l hello guy how are you ?"
  hello guy how are you ?
 % set l "$l chocolate is very good"
  hello guy how are you ? chocolate is very good
```

OR

```
 % set l [list]
 % append l "hello guy how are you ?"
 hello guy how are you ?
 % append l " chocolate is very good"
 hello guy how are you ? chocolate is very good
```